# What motor will work best as a generator for low torque input?

Tags: ac, dc, generator

I would like to know what kind of motor will work best as a generator.

The input will be RPM with low torque around 20-40 N*mm (this is the minimum.) It should be possible to rotate the motor at this torque and will be nice if I can produce 50W.

Have a type of motor that you suggest?

Extra info:

- If it can produce more power, it's a plus.
- It should be as small as possible.
- It should be brushless.

Comment: Conservation of energy tells us you'd need more than 15,000 RPM to get 50W.

Comment: I calculated round about 12000rpm, ignoring any losses. So I second the 15000rpm Sphero gave you.

Comment: You should rephrase this as "how do I pick a motor".

Comment: A regular permanent magnet brushless motor should work. The KV will determine the voltage/current relationship. We can't say what value is good unless we know more about the energy harvesting circuit.

Comment: We also need to know more about the source of mechanical energy. How does it's torque vary by RPMs?